# Is there a way to route to html files with Vue router?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, robotframework, vue-router

Hello I am using VueJS and the webpack template. I have a bunch of components I can easily display with Vue Router. However, my organization uses Robot Framework for testing and we generate an HTML page using the command:

```
python -m robot.testdoc /tests/directory /destination.html
```

This is basically how I am using the router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Main from '@/components/Main.vue'
import Component1 from '@/components/Component1.vue'
import Component2 from '@/components/Component2.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      mode: history,
      name: 'Main',
      component: Main
    },
    {
      path: '/component1',
      mode: history,
      name: 'Component1',
      component: Component1
    },
    {
      path: '/component2',
      mode: history,
      name: 'Component2',
      component: Component2
    }
  ]
})
```

Is there a way to route to an HTML file using Vue Router?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you'll need `html-loader`:

```
yarn add html-loader | npm install html-loader
```

Then you need to update your `webpack.config.js` file and add an entry to your `rules` to handle `.html` extensions:

```
{
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: {
      loader: "html-loader"
    }
}
```

Then you can import your `.html` files like you would components:

```
import Destination from '/path/to/destination.html'
```

Now treat `component` as an Object and leverage the `template` property to serve static HTML files:

```
 {
  path: '/destination',
  mode: history,
  name: 'destination',
  component: { template: Destination }
}
```

Comment: I have three webpack configuration js files: webpack.base.conf.js, webpack.dev.conf.js, and webpack.prod.conf.js. I am assuming I have to add it to all three?

Comment: Would it be easier to implement with a Vue CLI 3 generated project?

Comment: @KevinPatrick if `base` is being imported into the `prod` and `dev` files, then you can just do it in base. Doing it in Vue CLI 3 wouldn't make it any easier, per se, just a different configuration.

Comment: Okay, i made the changes in ```base``` and it basically served a blank html page. does ```component: { template: Destination }``` wrap the file in ```<template></template``` ?

Answer (score 1):

1.install html-loader

```
npm install --save-dev html-loader
```

2.use below code vue.config.js or Webpack.config.js

For webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

For Vue cli users vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
          .rule('html')
          .test(/\.html$/)
          .use('html-loader')
          .loader('html-loader')
      }
}
```

just add router in your

```
{
        path: '/print',
        name: 'print',

        component: () => import('../pages/print.html'),

    },
```

more about vue
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#replacing-loaders-of-a-rule