# How to add the original old html file with script and css markup ,and make it work in the vue project which uses component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

what I have done:
add a route with this HTML;
browser display a pure HTML page without the scripts and CSS being working;

I want to use a previous HTML page in nowadays vue project

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="...css"/>
</head>
<body>
     <div></div>
    <script src=""></script>
    <script src=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

route like this:

```
{path: "/example3", component: {template: Example3}},
```

Comment: How did you embed that html in the  `.vue` file? Did you put it in a vue file indeed?

Comment: nope. I just add a route like that above.

Comment: Ok, if you're to build a hybrid app, routing some to html files; have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53174823/4636715 . But, I'd rather create a vue file and mount the html, js and css in that since that solution seems to require webpack configuration which is probably more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks! but how to handle <script> loading thing.