# How can I use a router-link Vue with a li

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a template in bootstrap and I do not want to lose the design if I use Vue router-link. My button have this design:

```
<!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
<li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
   <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
   <span>Inicio</span></a>
</li>
```

I am using Vue but I want to keep same design so I wonder how can I add router-link without losing the design.

I tried this and it did not work:

```
<!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
<li class="nav-item active">
  <router-link class="nav-link" to="index.html">
  <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
   <span>Inicio</span></router-link>
</li>
```

It did not work. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: That's weird because by defaul router-link resolved to <a>

Comment: have you tried `this.router.push`?

Comment: I do not get it @DavidGo

Comment: I mean if the problem is that your design brakes then that's weird cause the tag <a> should be the same. But if the problem is that your routing doesn't work, then check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53174823/is-there-a-way-to-route-to-html-files-with-vue-router

Comment: Your `to` attribute doesn't look right for a Vue Router path. Usually it's something like `to="/"` or `:to="{ name: 'Home' }"`